# Making an image larger using java script when clicked on

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am trying to get my script working with my html to insure when the images are clicked on that they come up larger. When you click on the image I want to be able to see the homepage. When I click on the images nothing happens..Please help!

```
   <script type = "text/javascript">

function lightBox () {
    document.getElementById("BG").style.display = "block";
    document.getElementById("PG").style.display = "block";
}

function hideBox() {
    document.getElementById("BG").style.display = "none";
    document.getElementById("PG").style.display = "none";

}

</script>

<h1> My Page </h1>


<div id "BG" onClick "Box();">



</div>


<div id = "FG">

<img src = "sunset_1.jpg" width = "100" height = "60">


</div>


<div id = "thumb">

<img src = "sunset_1.jpg" width = "100" height = "60" onClick ="lightBox();">
<img src = "sunset_2.jpg" width = "100" height= "60"onClick ="lightBox();"> 
<img src = "sunset_3.jpg" width= "100" height="60" onClick ="lightBox();"> 
<img src = "sunset_4.jpg" width= "100" height= "60" onClick ="lightBox();">


</div>
 <p>

Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum

Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non

</p>




#BG  {
        width :100%;
        height:100%;
        background-color:#000;
        position: fixed;
        opacity: 0.8;
        -moz-opacity:0.8;
        -webkit-opacity:0.8;
        display:none;
        cursor: pointer;

}

#FG {

        border:1px solid #ccc;
        background-color:#fcfcfc;
        position: fixed;
        height:350px;
        width:550px;
        left:50%;
        margin-left:-275px;
        top:50px;
        display: none;
}
```

Comment: Would you post a code snippet? It would help.

Comment: You could try scaling the image on click using css by changing the class with javascript perhaps.

Answer (score 0):

Your code is a bit shaky, however sticking with your approach, this might help.

Here's some of the modified HTML, see [**this JSFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/occursys/93csvb9t/) for changes to CSS and JavaScript.

```
<h1> My Page </h1>

<div id="BG" onClick="FG_clicked();">
    <div id="FG">
    <img src="http://placehold.it/900x400">
</div>
</div>

<div id="thumb">
    <img src="http://placehold.it/350x150" width="100" height="60" onClick="lightBox();">
    <img src="http://placehold.it/350x150" width="100" height="60" onClick="lightBox();">
    <img src="http://placehold.it/350x150" width="100" height="60" onClick="lightBox();">
    <img src="http://placehold.it/350x150" width="100" height="60" onClick="lightBox();">
</div>
```

Comment: Yes my code is shaky at the best of times lol!Thanks so much!Just one more small question if you wouldn't mind, I just need the larger   to be the image I click on..

Comment: Here's one way to do that using the original image and just increasing the width: http://jsfiddle.net/occursys/r0owu9j4/ - but if you have thumbnail versions of your images, you would want to do this differently.

Comment: Perfect thanks very much! I just need to put a label on each picture that pops up with each for example, picture one, picture two..Any idea how this would be done?

Comment: You could add a title attribute for each image, and use that as the label, here's a quick example http://jsfiddle.net/occursys/o7kv7s53/

Comment: Thanks a million!You were a great help!

Comment: You're welcome! Please mark the question as accepted if this helped and good luck with the project.